# Language to describe a number smaller than, but related to Bell number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, factorial

I understand that the Bell number $B_n$ is the number of partitions of a set of size $n$. Despite my incredible ineptitude at combinatorics, I also understand most of how the binomial coefficient works (formulas, basic properties, a bound or two). However, I'm looking for something that describes the number of ways you can cut a set $S$ of size $n$ into, say, 2 disjoint partitions, or 3 partitions, or $k<n$ partitions. Is there terminology to describe this, a nice expression, or nice upper bounds?

I tried looking for bounds on the sum of binomial coefficients from $2$ to $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ (since every combination is a disjoint subset), which led me to [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.44.9677), but those bounds are exponential in $n$ (would be nice to find polynomial), and I think I'm doing more work than I need to (but I have bad intuition for combinatorics, so I'm not sure).

Can I just replace 3 with 2 and finagle $k$ in [this answer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/58858/60166)

Comment: Are the partitions nonempty?

Comment: Yes, the sum of the size of all partitions should equal the size of the original set, and each partition should be of size greater than 1.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind

Comment: "...count the number of ways to partition a set of n labelled objects into k nonempty unlabelled subsets." Sounds like it, although I don't know what "unlabelled" means here.

Comment: I think they mean that the order of the subsets doesn't matter, e.g., $(\{1\},\{2,3\})$ is the same as $(\{2,3\},\{1\})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you want to find the number of ways to partition a set of n elements into k subsets or less, all of these non-empty and without the order of the partitions mattering.

Then this is the same as $\sum_{j=1}^k S(n,j)$ where $S(n,j)$ denotes the number of way so partition a set of n elements into j subsets without the partitions being "labelled".

the numbers $S(n,m)$ are called the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).